# Checking if an array has some items in coffeescript

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

Is there some method in coffeescript that returns true when an array has some items in it? Like method in ruby `present?`:

```
[].present? false
[1].present? true
```

According to http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/07_the_bad_parts.html an array emptiness in coffeescript is determined by its length

```
alert("Empty Array")  unless [].length
```

that seems so lame to me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think there is but can be:

```
Array::present = ->
  @.length > 0

if [42].present()
  # why yes of course
else
  # oh noes
```

A very simple and incomplete implementation but it should give you some ideas. And for the record, there's no `present?` method in Ruby, the method is added by the `active_support` gem.

Comment: For clarity I would go for `empty()` (like `empty?` in Ruby). Slightly less dubious IMHO.

Comment: @Cimm I think both are methods in Ruby's Array class, and both are common from what I've seen.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there isn't. The best way to do it is by comparing its length.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `in` works as well.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = 1
if a in arr
  console.log 'present'
else
  console.log 'not present'

Output
$ present
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.